# success block not executing in $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am passing data to array and i want to send this array via ajax to my views.py. But on running only the error block gets executed.

**JQuery**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var arr=[];
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".addtocart").click(function(){
          arr.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());
      });
      $("#show").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:'{% url "curr_order" %}',
          data: {'arr[]': arr},
          success:function(data){
              alert(data.order)
          },
          error: function(){
             alert("Error");
          }
      });
});
  });
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def curr_order(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    order = request.POST.getlist('arr[]')
    response = {'order': order}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^curr_order/$',views.curr_order, name ='curr_order')
```

My questions are:
1) Now on running alertbox with Error is shown. Why isnt success block not executing? And how do i correct it?
2) How do I display all array elements? `data.order` wont show all the elements I think.

Thanks!

Comment: Check error you get then

Comment: Use the network tab of the console to see the exact status code and error description.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some parameters in your error block and report what the actual error is.  Then you might be able to see what needs to be fixed.

Example - here I log the status which has been set to the actual error that occurred:

```
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            logerror("Error retrieving data: " + status);
        });
```

Comment: I don't think that's an answer to the question, it's better to move it into comment section to get more info first then post a solution.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment because I just joined Stack Overflow yesterday, but I still wanted to help.

Comment: Ah, OK. But be sure to edit your answer when you have a complete solution.